# Kubuntu Energy Saving event on power button pressed not working

Tags: 13.10, kubuntu, power-management, hibernate

My Aspire 1810TZ is running Kubuntu 13.10 on an encrypted drive. I have enabled hibernation in file

`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

I CAN hibernate and resume with
`sudo pm-hibernate`
and by using the application launcher ( "**Leave - Hibernate**" )

I set "**Energy Saving - Button Events Handling**" to "**Sleep when laptop lid closed**" and to "**Hibernate when power button pressed**" (for AC power, battery and low battery mode each). Sleep mode works fine.

When I press the power button the system shuts down / hibernates. But when switching it on again it just boots normally and has to start the open applications again.

So my question: What is the difference between the event "**when power button pressed**" and `sudo pm-hibernate`?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself. It's a bug. More info here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-workspace/+bug/1124149

What worked for me was to edit powerbutton.sh

```
sudo nano /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

and change the last line

```
/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
```

to

```
:: /sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
```

Comment: THIS WORKS!!!!! I followed the link to the bug report and forgot about this answer, and ending up trying a bunch of other suggestions I found there (changing symlinks, installing different packer versions, etc) before finally stumbling back across this answer. (Hence the all caps, not-entirely-sane-shoutpole-use comment; Redirect future me-oids to pay more attention to this answer first. ^^;; )