# Can't configure physical power button to sleep? "Battery Monitor Settings" GUI claims it already is

Tags: kubuntu, configuration, suspend

I can't configure my laptop to sleep when I press the physical power button.

I chose that option in the "Battery Monitor Settings" GUI (for all power states), but it still turns off whenever I press it.

The sleep option in the kickstarter menu works fine, though.

(I also chose the "do nothing" option for when I close the lid. This works fine, so it's not like *everything* in the GUI is just not having an effect...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/378795/46331

> `sudo nano /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`
>
> and change the last line
>
> `/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"`
>
> to
>
> `:: /sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"`

Comment: Better patch probably: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd-shim/+bug/1201180/comments/19